# Question about package of cookies that is a random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, proof-verification

The weight in grams of package of cookies is a random variable with expected value  of $300$ grams

> $\color{blue}{A)}$ assume that X is normally distributed with standard deviation of $15 $ grams
>
> $\color{blue}{(A_1)}$ What is the probability that in random purchase  of package of cookies the weight of the package will be $276-312$ grams?
>
> $\color{blue}{(A_2)} $ If $5\%$ from all the packages are under the standard of the lowest weight that is allowed for package, what is the standard?
>
> $\color{blue}{B)}$ answer on $\color{blue}{(A_1)}$,$\color{blue}{(A_2)}$ if $X$ exponential distributed

My attempt:

$\color{blue}{(A_1)}$

$$P(276\leq X \leq 312)=F_{_X}(312)-F_{_X}(276)=\Phi\bigg(\frac{312-300}{15}\bigg)-\Phi\bigg(\frac{276-300}{15}\bigg)=\Phi\bigg(\frac{12}{15}\bigg)-\Phi\bigg(\frac{-24}{15}\bigg)=\Phi\bigg(0.8\bigg)-\Phi\bigg(-1.6\bigg)=\Phi\bigg(0.8\bigg)-1+\Phi\bigg(1.6\bigg)\stackrel{\text{table}}{=}0.7881-1+0.9452=\boxed{0.7333}$$

$\color{blue}{A_2)}$

$P(X<\alpha)=5\%$

$\alpha=t+300$

$P(X<t+300)=P(X-300<t)=P\bigg(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}<\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\bigg)=P\bigg(\frac{X-300}{15}<\frac{t}{15}\bigg)=0.05$

$\Phi\bigg(\frac{t}{15}\bigg)=0.05$

$\Phi\bigg(\frac{t}{15}\bigg)=1-\Phi\bigg(-\frac{t}{15}\bigg)=0.05 $

$$0.95=\Phi\bigg(-\frac{t}{15}\bigg)$$

$$-\frac{t}{15}\stackrel{\text{table}}{=}1.645$$

$$t=-24.675=\alpha=t+300$$

$$\Longrightarrow \boxed{\alpha=275.325}$$

$\color{blue}{B_1)}$

$$X\sim \exp(\lambda),\;E[X]=\frac{1}{\lambda}=300,\; \sigma=15$$

$$P(276<X<312)=P(X<312)-P(X<276)$$

$$=1-e^{-\frac{1}{300}\cdot 312}-1+e^{-\frac{1}{300}\cdot 276}\approx \boxed{0.0451}$$

$\color{blue}{B_2)}$

$$P(X<\alpha)=0.05,\;\alpha=t+300$$

$$P(X<t+300)=0.05$$

$$1-e^{\frac{-t-300}{300}}=0.05$$

$$e^{\frac{-t-300}{300}}=0.95$$

$$\frac{-t-300}{300}=\ln(0.95)$$

$$-t-300=\ln(0.95)\cdot 300+300$$

$$t=284.61$$

$$\alpha=\boxed{15.387}$$

> Is it correct? Is there other methods to solve this?

Comment: The procedures are basically right.  In B, there is typo towards the end, you should (and probably did) get $t$ large negative.

Comment: The $t+300$ stuff  just complicates the typing for the exponential, you should work directly with $a\pha$.  Also, there is a mistake/typo in the third line from the end.

Comment: Yes, I will try the other why with $\alpha$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedures are basically right. I have not checked the numerical details.

There are a  couple of issues somewhere between typos and errors in the second part of Problem B. The third displayed line from the end should read $-t-300=300\ln(0.95)$. The next line should read $t=-284.61$.  But the $\alpha$ obtained in the last line is correct.

There was no need to introduce the $t$. Directly we have $e^{-\alpha/300}=0.95$, so $\alpha=-300\ln(0.95)$.